# Gulp webapp generator sass sourcemaps

Tags: yeoman, gulp, yeoman-generator, source-maps, gulp-sass

I can't get sass sourcemaps to work, i set this in gulpfile:

Sass task snippet form Gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('styles', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/styles/main.scss')
        .pipe($.rubySass({
            style: 'expanded',
            precision: 10,
            sourcemap: true
        }))
        .pipe($.autoprefixer('last 1 version'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/styles'))
        .pipe(reload({stream:true}))
        .pipe($.size());
});
```

The `main.css.map` file actually generates under `.tmp/styles` next to `main.css`, but it does not gets read by the browser. I am using the [generator-gulp-webapp](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-gulp-webapp) form yeoman with [BrowserSync](http://browsersync.io/).

BrowserSync snippet from gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('serve', ['styles'], function () {
    browserSync.init(null, {
        server: {
            baseDir: ['app', '.tmp'],
            directory: true
        },
        debugInfo: false,
        open: false,
        host: "localhost"
    }, function (err, bs) {
        require('opn')(bs.options.url);
        console.log('Started connect web server on ' + bs.options.url);
    });
});
```